# Regular Expression to extract numbers from age range DataFrame column with multiple formats

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract the high and low numbers from a column that has multiple formats.

For instance,

- if the value is: 'Age 34 - 35', I want to collect (34, 35)
- if the value is: '35-44 years old', I want to collect (35, 44)
- if the value is: '75+ years old, I am fine collecting (75, '')

I currently have a regex written that works for some of the formats but not for others:

```
dataframe[['age_low', 'age_high]] = dataframe['age'].str.extract(r'(\d*)[\s-]*(\d*)')
```

Here are all the possible values in the original age column:

`dataframe['age'].unique()`

```
array([nan, 'Age 34 - 35 ', 'Age 78 - 79 ', 'Age 60 - 61 ',
       'Age 50 - 51 ', 'Age 20 - 21 ', 'Age 70 - 71 ', 'Age 82 - 83 ',
       'Age 88 - 89 ', 'Age 68 - 69 ', 'Age 86 - 87 ', 'Age 84 - 85 ',
       'Age 46 - 47 ', 'Age 30 - 31', 'Age 94 - 95 ', 'Age 22 - 23 ',
       'Age 44 - 45 ', 'Age 74 - 75 ', 'Age 40 - 41', 'Age 72 - 73 ',
       'Age 52 - 53 ', 'Age 48 - 49 ', 'Age 66 - 67 ', 'Age 62 - 63 ',
       'Age 56 - 57 ', 'Age 64 - 65 ', 'Age 38 - 39 ', 'Age 42 - 43 ',
       'Age 54 - 55 ', 'Age 24 - 25 ', 'Age 90 - 91 ', 'Age 76 - 77 ',
       'Age 58 - 59 ', 'Age 32 - 33', 'Age 26 - 27 ', 'Age 80 - 81 ',
       'Age 28 - 29 ', 'Age 36 - 37', 'Age 96 - 97 ',
       'Age greater than 99', 'Age 18 - 19', 'Age 92 - 93 ',
       'Age 98 - 99 ','65-74 years old', '35-44 years old', '45-54 years old',
       '75+ years old', '55-64 years old', '25-34 years old',
       '18-24 years old'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Try `r'(\d+)(?:[\s-]*(\d+))?'` or `r'(\d+)[\s-]*(\d*)'`

Answer (score 0):

For the possible values in your question that only have one age value, that age always represents the low side of the range. As a result, you could just capture the first one or more digits in the string and then use a non-capture group to indicate a potential following sequence of non-digits followed by another group of one or more digits. If there is a second age in the string, it will get captured as the high side of the range. If there is only one age, you will just get a `NaN` value for the high side of the range.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

ages = ['Age 96 - 97', 'Age greater than 99', '65-74 years old', '75+ years old']
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': ages})

df[['age_low', 'age_high']] = df['age'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?')
print(df)
#                    age age_low age_high
# 0          Age 96 - 97      96       97
# 1  Age greater than 99      99      NaN
# 2      65-74 years old      65       74
# 3        75+ years old      75      NaN
```